# cookie free subdomain and @font-face

Tags: css, cookies

I've set up a cookie-free subdomain.
In my css i use @font-face:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Butterfly Kids;
src:url(fonts/butterfly/Butterfly-Kids.ttf.woff) format('woff'),
    url(fonts/butterfly/Butterfly-Kids.ttf.svg#Butterfly-Kids) format('svg'),
    url(fonts/butterfly/Butterfly-Kids.ttf.eot),
    url(fonts/butterfly/Butterfly-Kids.ttf.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'); 
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

But the font does not appear.
I've tried to set the path like:

```
src(https://static.domain.com/fonts/butterfly/Butterfly-Kids.ttf.woff) format('woff'), etc.
```

This did't bring up the font either.
Does anyone know how to set the path for @font-face with a cookie-free
subdomain?
Thanks for your interest.
theo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@font-face does not require cookies (unless you choose to cache fonts to avoid server hits), and having a subdomain will make no difference either.

You may therefore have an issue with your URLs. Your paths in the first (multiple-line) example are relative to your css file; is your 'fonts' directory in the same directory as the css file? If not, that is your issue (or one issue).

Also, check your font file formats. All your fonts have 'ttf' (TrueType) as the first file extension, but they can't also be .eot (Embedded Open Type), .svg (Scalable Vector Graphics) and so forth: those are different file formats. Make sure all your font files are actually in the correct format.

Comment: Thanks for the message. Yes, the fonts folder is in the same directory as the style.css. So, it must be your third suggestion. I'll try to change that.

Comment: Check out [CSS-Tricks: Using @font-face](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) for some other helpful pointers on file formats.

Comment: I changed it to: src:url(fonts/butterfly/Butterfly-Kids.woff) format('woff'), etc. but the fonts won't show up.

Comment: What browser are you using? I notice you don't have a .ttf entry (format 'truetype') for some Safari, Android and iOS browsers.

Comment: And just to check: did you just duplicate a .ttf file before and give it different file extensions (.woff etc)? Because that won't work. :) They're different file formats.

Comment: i use firefox. No i didn't duplicate the files. Everything works fine when i disable the cookie-free domain. I also checked the link you gave me, but that didn't change anything. I am loading different fonts and the butterfly example is just one of them. They all are good without subdomain. Butterfly even renders in safari 9. Strange, i don't get it.